# XCode 5 - Remove offline documentation?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to remove all/most *offline* documentation from XCode 5, to free up disk space?

I would assume it is possible to make XCode (like Visual Studio in Windows) access documentation *online*, so removing offline documentation doesn't affect any functionality. Yes?

Answer (score 14):

Xcode 5, 6 and 7 documentation itself is located within:

```
~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
```

You can delete the files and when you re-launch Xcode, it will offer to re-download the current docs if you have automatic updates set.

Before deleting actual documentation, make sure your downloads folder for the images that contain the installers and the documentation are cleaned out:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads
```

**If you do decide to delete the documentation itself you will no longer have access to it through Xcode** — so be careful not to delete the Core DocSets, or any others that you might need access to regularly as you don't fail over gracefully to the web documentation.

The documentation that is available for download through XCode is not simply a mirror of what Apple shows online. The docs available online amount to about 1/2 of what is actually available from the more comprehensive downloaded versions. Online documentation can also be updated to a newer build of Xcode, so downloading a copy ensures you have the correct documentation for your version of Xcode.

Comment: "The docs available online amount to about 1/2 of what is actually available from the more comprehensive downloaded versions." That's odd. Shouldn't it be the other way round in today's day and age of high speed internet and cloud storage? In any case documentation is a resource that (should) keep changing/getting updated, including minor typo fixes, something a central online repository facilitates greatly...so I see no reason for why it should be the way you say it is. (of course offline documentation has the benefit of speed/offline access, which is ideal for just the *core* documentation.)

Comment: Well that's the thing, Apple is constantly updating/revising docs, but often times they simply remove portions, which then might only be available for download through XCode. I can't tell you how many times I've tried to go to a linked online documentation page only to find it no longer exists.

Comment: Forgive the large edits - revert/roll back if you disagree with any of it. If you cut it all out, would you ping me so I can post a second answer. I felt making your answer more updated was preferable, but perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: @bmike: No apology necessary, in fact thank you — some things have changed since I answered this question so it's only helpful :)